# Ramsey and Random Graph

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory, random-graphs

By considering the random graph G(n,p), show that

$$R(4,k)>\left ( \dfrac{k}{3\log k} \right )^{3/2} $$

Improve this bound as much as you can.

Comment: There's no apparent connection between the two sides. Are $t$ and $k$ related?

Comment: I'm sorry. $k=t$ :D edited.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be done via [probabilistic method](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2005/Expanders/notes/prob-method-intro.pdf). As a hint, show that

$$\binom{n}{k}p^{\binom{k}{2}}+\binom{n}{t}(1-p)^{\binom{t}{2}}<1$$

Which will imply $R(k,t)>n$. After you do this, you'll be able to show your bound with a little extra work.